# adding multiple regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to validate my password such that it must contain small alphabets, capital alphabets, digits and special characters.
My code looks like this:

```
if (password.length < 8 || !/([a-zA-Z])/.test(password) || !/([0-9])/.test(password) || !/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/.test(password)){
     console.log('Error: password is too weak');
}
```

As you can see I have put up many tests in the `if` condition. Can I make it a single regex to achieve my purpose?

Comment: I think your regexps don't do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

if (!regex.test(password)) {
    console.log('Error: password is too weak');
}
```

`(?=.*[a-z])` checks if password contains at least 1 lowercase character

`(?=.*[A-Z])` checks if password contains at least 1 uppercase character

`(?=.*[0-9])` checks if password contains at least 1 numeric character

`(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])` checks if password contains at least 1 special character.

`(?=.{8,})` checks if password contains at least 8 characters or more.

Comment: If I have to make sure that the password can not have the characters out of above mentioned options, how do I ensure that?

Comment: What do you mean? The code I wrote is a working piece of code, just replace it with your own and test it..

Comment: I mean, I want my password to have only alphabets, digits and special characters I have listed. I also want to ensure that the user can't input any other characters in the password other than alphanumerals and special characters listed above.